# Change value, add and remove fields of deep nested object with useState hook in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, use-state

The nested state object is like this:

```
 key1: {
      key2: [
        {
          field1: "value",
          field2: ["value", "value"],
          field3: [
            {
              ff1: "val",
              ff2: ["val"],
              ff3: [
                [{ f1: "v", f2: 1 },
                 { f1: "v", f2: 2 
                 }],
                [
                  { f1: "v", f2: 1 },
                  { f1: "v", f2: 2 },
                ],
              ],
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    }
```

I just couldn't figure it out how should I update the state with useState hook set function.

provided that the updating levels are :

```
key1.key2
key1.key2[index].field1 = value
key1.key2[index].field2[index] = value
key1.key2[index].field3[index].ff2[index] = value
key1.key2[index].field3[index].ff3[index][index].key = value
```

and also **adding** and **removing** the key value pairs in those levels!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deep copy the current state, make desired changes, and pass back to the setter.

LoDash Clone Deep: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#cloneDeep

Another option is to use [immer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/immer). This library allows you to use code that seems to modify the existing object but is actually generating a new object without a complete deep copy.

Immer example: https://immerjs.github.io/immer/

Comment: @SaikatDey I updated the answer to include links to examples of each.

Comment: I'm using immer and it works well. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have your state declared like this:

```
const [key, setKey1] = useState(initialState);
```

You can use the setKey1 function that will give you the actual state, make your changes on it and return it like that:

```
setKey1(oldState => {
  oldState.key2[0].field1 = "test";
  oldState.key2[0].field2[0] = "test";
  oldState.key2[0].field3[0].ff2[0] = "test";
  oldState.key2[0].field3[0].ff3[0][0].key = "test";

  //adding
  oldState.key2[0].field2.push('new_value');
  
  //deleting
  delete oldState.key2[0].field3[0].ff3[0][0].f1;

  return {...oldState};
});
```

You can find a working codepen [here](https://codepen.io/tanguyroberjot/pen/yLMyEPN?editors=0011)

Comment: This is not reliable, because the update function is returning the same object. ["Mutating state in place and calling setState will not cause a re-render."](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-there-something-like-forceupdate). One way to make this more reliable is to return a new object at the end which guarantees that React will rerender: `return { ...oldstate }`

Comment: this is the simplest solution for the task. but for future best practice I would go for immer.
@TanguyRoberjot many thanks for replying and also confirming my initial idea about state update.